# How can I make Speedfan run automatically when the PC starts?

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I tweaked the fan curve on my case fan because it runs at 100% when I am gaming. So I made it run at a max of 80%, which is MUCH more quieter, and it doesn't seem to have any impact on the max temperatures of my components under load. I tested 20 mins under 100% load before/after, reducing the fan speed by 20% had zero impact on any temperature readings. This may possibly be due to the fact that I recently upgraded my PSU, which has 120mm fan so it also helps to exhaust air out of the case.

But the problem is, unlike MSI Afterburner (which I used to control the fan speed of my GPU), I can't seem to find an option to make Speedfan auto run at startup.

If this is not possible with Speedfan, are there any other similar programs that can control the speed of my case fan and run automatically when the PC starts up?

Thanks!

Comment: Though interesting the first paragraph of your answer is not related to your question? Or is it? Would probably be advisable to omit the first paragraph.

Answer (score 7):

I have gone the route of making batch files for programs that I want to run when windows starts. For speedfan use the following:

1. Open Windows Notepad and type:

   ```
   @ECHO off
   start speedfan.exe
   ```
2. Save this in the same directory as where your speedfan.exe is located and make sure you save it as a batch file (e.g. use dropdown to change file type to all and then name the file `speedfan.bat`).
3. Create a shortcut to the file you just created and place it in the `shell:startup` folder and cross your fingers.

For whatever reason, this is the only consistent way I've found of getting certain programs to run that don't properly auto start.

As a caveat, sometimes the startup folder won't let you paste a shortcut due to permissions so make sure you take ownership through security options of the shell:startup folder if it gives you a hard time. Seriously Windows 10 can be a pain when it comes to permissions.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using Windows' Task Scheduler: `taskschd.msc`

**Caveat:** Unfortunately SpeedFan's icon will not appear in notification tray area but it will still control your fan speeds.

**Assumptions:**

- `MyHost\User1` is any user with administrative privileges
- `C:\Program Files\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe` is the path to the SpeedFan executable
- `/NOACPISCAN /NOSMBSCAN` are the arguments to run SpeedFan

---

**Instructions to create the Task:**

1. Start `taskschd.msc` with administrator/elevated privileges
2. Click `Create Task...`
3. Under the `General` Tab:

   - Name: `SpeedFan`
   - Description: `Start SpeedFan on System Start-up`
   - When running the task, use the following user account: `MyHost\User1`

     - `Select`: Run whether user is logged on or not
     - `Un-check`: Do not store password...
     - `Check`: Run with highest privileges
   - Configure for: `Windows 7...`
4. Under the `Triggers` Tab:

   - Click `New...`
   - Begin the task: `At startup`

     - `Check`: Delay task for: 2 minutes
     - `Check`: Repeat task every: `1 hour` for a duration of: `Indefinitely`
     - `Check`: Enabled
5. Under the `Actions` Tab:

   - Start a program:
   - Program: `"C:\Program Files\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe"`
   - Add Arguments: `/NOACPISCAN /NOSMBSCAN`
   - Start in: `C:\Program Files\SpeedFan\`

     *Note: Don't use quotes on the `Start in` path!*
6. Under the `Conditions` Tab:

   - `Un-check`: All options
7. Under the `Settings` Tab:

   - `Only Check`:

     - Allow task to be run on demand
     - If the task fails, restart every: `10 minutes`

       - Attempt to restart up to: `3 times`
   - If task is already running: `Do not start a new instance`
8. Click `OK`

   - Enter user account credentials if prompted

Answer (score 2):

- Go to start, type Run.
- Type shell:startup
- copy paste the shortcut of Speedfan in that folder
- Reboot, it should start once you're in.
- to remove it, just delete the shortcut.

Comment: This doesn't work. In Task Manager Speedfan shows up as a startup-enabled program, but it doesn't actually seem to run until I click on the icon on the desktop to launch it.

Is the fact that I have to accept the UAC anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

after googling I didn't get it work because it needs elevation, Task Scheduler way, or others, didn't work for me, so I put a shortcut to a .cmd in
"%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"   like that:

```
REM Elevate Permissions routine - Thanks to murphy78
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
(NET FILE||(powershell -command Start-Process '%0' -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '%* '&EXIT /B))>NUL 2>NUL
REM Elevation Routine Ends

start "SpeedFan" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe"
```

it needs user confirm elevation but it work...

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop a shortcut to the program (speedfan) over into the Start menu (start orb).
Keep the drag going until you have placed it into the "all Programs" and into the "startup" section/folder.  (a line will show for the location it will land , dont drop it till you see that)

To minimise it, Right click and select properties on the shortcut and set the "Run" property to "Minimised" , and speedfan will minimise into the tray.

In the "configuration" section of speedfan select "Show in tray" if that does not work.
In The main/first speedfan screen select "Automatic fan speed" , as it defaults to off, as a safety measure. (you already probably did this)

Remember if speedfan should crash , or some other program would cause it to crash, you could reach critical temperatures. While rare it has happened to people, so be sure to check well before relying on it. Check also that it is working correct after standby/sleep occurances.

If you have UAC issues, think about running it up at startup via the Task Scheduler , where it can run with various permissions you set there. It might take some adjusting to perfect it, but that is one possible method.

Comment: Honestly, unless it crashes while I am playing a game at full load, I doubt there would be any major impact on my system temperature. But I will definitely keep this in mind and check on the temps/fanspeed using HW Monitor from time to time.

I did add Speedfan to the startup folder but it doesn't seem to actually be working unless I click on the icon on the desktop to launch it. Is the fact that I have to accept the UAC anything to do with it?

Comment: I see that, I dont actually use "users" or that control so I don't have that issue, but i did add at the bottom a possible method that has been used for other programs when having that problem , the Task Scheduler. That thing can run programs or scripts at startup or log-in, with access.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to have it start through task scheduler, but I do have a rainmeter widget on my desktop that gives a readout. Through task scheduler it wont give a reading to rainmeter. The fix I've found that works for my particular set up is as Twisty Impersonator suggested. Making a shortcut to a .bat file works just fine. I have Windows 10. Speedfan starts up when logging into my personal profile and is giving readings to rainmeter widget. If you want the main startup folder for all users that would be, win+R> shell: common startup

Comment: Please refer this link,, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer help you to compose an improved post!

Answer (score 0):

Create the task in Task Scheduler just as said as "Moo", but don't put as startup type as "at startup". Instead of this put as "at logon".

I created this for speedfan 4.52 in Windows 10 64 bit and it is started successfully with user intervention.

**no user intervention**:  set UAC "Notify me only when apps try to make changes to my computer (default)" to "Never notify".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I created this for speedfan 4.52 in Windows 10 64 bit and it is started successfully with user intervention.

Isn't the point to start WITHOUT user intervention?

Changing the "User Account Control (UAC) settings" to "Never notify" is a serious security risk under the Windows Operating System opening the door for viruses/trojans/malware to sneak in without the user's knowledge since the UAC prompt will "Never notify" the user!!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1156840)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).